# Warm white LED lamp recommendations?

Tags: headlight, led

Almost all LED headlamps I'm able to find produce white light. Can anyone recommend any Warm-White lamps by major manufacturers?

Comment: That may be a market specific product...

Comment: Headlight color rating is called "color temperature". Warm white would probably be around 4000k - 4300k. Because the rating is a standard measurement, any light with a 4300k color temperature rating should have the same color. The lower the number, the more yellow the light is, and the higher the number, the more blue it is.

Here is a link to a chart of various color temperatures.
https://www.xenonpro.com/images/articles/xenon-hid-color-temerature-chart-table.png

I'd recommend reading ratings, and just buying something with a lot of 4+ star ratings.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Sorry for having to close this, however shopping questions are off-topic. However, @the_storyteller has good information for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really doesn't matter what the package says for color temp because those numbers are usually wrong. Recent testing by the SAE showed that most LED mfgrs color and lumen numbers are way off---no resemblence to reality.

See this post on LED headlights  https://ricksfreeautorepairadvice.com/sae-led-headlight-bulb-test-results/

Comment: Worth a comment, but an answer?